# Path is correct, folder structure too. Still getting problem message "The asset file xxx.tflite doesn't exist"

Tags: flutter, dart, assets, tflite, pubspec

In Flutter (VS Studio 2022) I am trying to use a .tflite model. This is my pubspec.yaml file;

```
name: linked_post_ai_v1
description: A description about your project.
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: '^3.2.0-65.0.dev'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  sqflite: ^2.0.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  tflite_flutter: ^0.10.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.4
  sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.3.0+2

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite
```

This is my folder structure:

root

-assets

-lib

--pubspec.yaml

--other.dart files

The model I want to use is in the assets folder, I checked the path a gazillion times by now. I tried other models too so I dont think the file is the problem. I tried about anything I could think of. Still getting this error:

```
The asset file 'assets\distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite' doesn't exist.
Try creating the file or fixing the path to the file.
```

I also tried \ and / in the path, neither work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: To be clear, you're getting this error message when trying to access the asset at runtime and not when you're bundling your asset, right?  The path you specified in your `pubspec.yaml` file is `assets\models\distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite`, but the error message indicates that you're trying to access `assets\distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite` without the `models` subdirectory.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear (I tried adding a models subdirectory at one point but thats not currently in the code / directory. This is my current pubspec.yaml:
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite

Still getting this error:
The asset file 'assets/distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite' doesn't exist.
Try creating the file or fixing the path to the file.

Comment: can you add ``- assets/`` before including the file ``- assets/distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite`` and try.

Comment: Can you give us code where you use this asset file

Comment: Are you sure that the actual name of the file (not just what's listed in `pubspec.yaml`) is all lowercase?

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I copied the name from my finder, Im pretty sure its correct at this point.

Comment: @MitchiJ And yet the path clearly is *not* correct because you're receiving an error.  You should be challenging your assumptions.  Also, presuming that you're observing a runtime error, unless you're running on a Windows system, you should definitely be using forward slashes (`/`).

Comment: @RajendraAVerma Here is the github; https://github.com/MitchelliJ/Linked_Post_AI_v1 I want to call on the asset file in new_post.dart.

Comment: @jamesdlin Im running on Windows. The error is preventing me from running the app.

Comment: [`package:tflite_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter) indicates that it supports Android and iOS platforms, [not Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/flutter-tflite/issues/64).

Comment: @jamesdlin Thats good to know as Im primarily running on Windows for testing. Im getting the same error on an android emulator tho.

Comment: When you say you get the *same* error on Android, does that mean you're trying to use backslashes as directory separators on Android?  And AFAICT [in the code you linked to on GitHub](https://github.com/MitchelliJ/Linked_Post_AI_v1/blob/d2942414f0e7d471ae95109ec1ed387a3d84f9f8/new_post.dart#L27), you don't even supply a path to your asset at all.  Can you please **edit your question** and show: 1. Your `pubspec.yaml` file, 2. The code that loads the asset, 3. The results of running `ls assets/distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite` on your dev machine.

Comment: 4. The *exact* error message you get (and on which platform) using the same code as shown in the previous steps.  Please do *not* make assumptions.  Currently it's hard to understand exactly what you're observing where with what state of your code.

Comment: Can you check for leading/trailing spaces in the filename in the assets folder?  And provide a screenshot of the file in the assets folder.

Comment: @jamesdlin Ill edit in a sec - new to stack overflow formatting. To answer your third question, this is what I'm getting in the terminal when running ls assets/distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite:

`    Directory: C:\FlutterApps\linked_post_ai_v1\assets`


`Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name`


`----                 -------------         ------ ----`


`-a----         8/14/2023  10:59 PM      162556076 distilgpt2-small-64-fp16.tflite`



`PS C:\FlutterApps\linked_post_ai_v1>`

Comment: @jamesdlin error pt1
  Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
  No file or variants found for asset: assets/lite-model_mobilebert_1_metadata_1.tflite.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(249,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\FlutterApps\linked_post_ai_v1\lib\build\windows\CMakeFiles\880e89cedd66bb73887c9421cc730872\flutter_windows.dll.rule;C:\FlutterApps\linked_post_ai_v1\lib\build\windows\CMakeFiles\603ba1b2eda3283cc5ae9299c4ab7215\flutter_assemble.rule' exited with code 1.

Comment: pt2: [C:\FlutterApps\linked_post_ai_v1\lib\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.

I get this when trying to run main.dart without debugging with Windows-x64 as connected device.

Comment: @pgs I just checked but there are no weird spaces in any file or folder names.

Answer (score -1):

can you please try removing the '-' from your file name?

It worked when I faced this issue.

Comment: I tried it but Im pretty sure it needs to be there to make a list from the string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).